# System.InvalidOperationException >> occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to ask about this problem please. this my code>

context :

```
public class ArchifeContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

Controller :

```
public ArchifeContext db = new ArchifeContext();

public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Books.ToList());
}
```

Comment: It's a pretty general error.  You'll need to use the stack trace or debugger to determine which line of code raised the error.  I doubt it was any of the code that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

This might be occurring because your database doesn't match your context, try to backup and delete old database and try again. If you don't wana do this then try to migrate changes to your database by using `Enable-Migrations` and `Update-Database`

Comment: Any info from Stack Trace?

Comment: An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The model backing the 'ArchifeContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database

Comment: Hey bro, this is because of reason as I mentioned above, are you using code first model? Your database and your models are not matching so you need to make them same, either go for migrating changes or make your model classes same to resemble database

Comment: Try Update-Database in PackageManager console.

Comment: Could you explain me solution (satisfying explanation) , I using SQlServer2012.

Comment: Please go through this, http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/migration-in-code-first.aspx you will get all the info you need.

Comment: model code:   public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id{ get; set; }

        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int EmployeeId  { get; set; }
        public DateTime PublishDate { get; set; }
        public int PublisherId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime UploadedDate { get; set; }

Comment: public HttpPostedFile ImageOfBook{ get; set; }
        public int UploaderId { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdadtedDate{ get; set; }
        public int UpdatorId{ get; set; }
        public string IsDeleted{ get; set; }
        public DateTime DeletedDate { get; set; }
        public int DeletorId { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: here context :
namespace ArchifeApps.Context
{
    public class ArchifeContext: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: Go to Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console. A new window will be opened, now run following commands over there, `Enable-Migrations` then `Add-Migration "MyMigration"` and finally, `Update-Database -Verbose`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.It worked for me

1. Enable-Migrations
2. Add-Migration
   (Migration Name)
3. update-database
4. Run Again